# Which is the correct way to use Java's date formats in Android Studio?

Tags: java, date, date-format, android-calendar

I am trying to build a chat app and I want to store date for every message in Firebase RealTime-Database using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` which stores date and time in milliseconds and it is server sided. All I want to achieve is to convert milliseconds to a safe date format which will have a pattern like "Thursday, 11th November 2022, 14:42" but I read a lot of things about Java's unsafe date and format libraries. My app uses FirebaseUI which is like an asynchronous way to observe/notify/listen to changes of my db so I need something that will be safe and supported from API/SDK level 21+

Here is my code that I currently have

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); calendar.setTimeInMillis(model.sentOnDateInMilliseconds); String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());`

and I make attempts to preview the format that I want like this

`textView.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0} {1}:{2} {3}", date, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)));`

any suggestions?

Comment: Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API through desugaring. You want classes `Instant`, `ZonedId` , `DateTimeFormatter` and possibly more. They are safe and a pleasure to use IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, or either `Date` class. These legacy classes are terribly flawed with poor design decisions by people who did not understand date-time handling.

Their modern replacements are the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Though not [documented clearly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.ServerValue#timestamp), apparently a `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` type represents a moment as a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

### `java.time.Instant`

The matching class in Java is [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

You can extract that millisecond count from an `Instant`. Beware of data loss: A `Instant` has a resolution of nanoseconds, so getting a count of milliseconds ignores the microseconds/nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

### `java.time.ZonedDateTime`

> convert milliseconds to a safe date format which will have a pattern like "Thursday, 11th November 2022, 14:42"

To generate text in formats other than standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), we need a class more flexible than `Instant`. And we need to adjust that moment from an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC to a time zone (or offset) expected by the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

### `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

To generate text, we must specify a format. You can hard-code a format, or you can let *java.time* automatically localize. To localize, we specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms needed for localization such as name of day of week.

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "instant = " + instant );
System.out.println( "millisSinceEpoch = " + millisSinceEpoch );
System.out.println( "output = " + output );
```

When run.

```
instant = 2022-11-18T19:27:22.561715Z
millisSinceEpoch = 1668799642561
output = Saturday, November 19, 2022 at 4:27:22 AM Japan Standard Time
```

---

Android 26+ carries an implementation of the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android, the latest tooling provides access to most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

Comment: Ok I achieved to get the results that I want using LocalDateTime, and DateTimeFormatter I read in documentations that these are classes of java.time library so I guess that is a better approach than the intial one isn't it? Should I go for ZonedDateTime? and what should I use for older Android versions? my app starts from api lvl 21.

Comment: The second scenario of your question is the one that fits to my thread, I have read many threads here on stack but I cannot find anything that comes close enough to my thread.

Comment: @iliasreventon Sorry, my previous Comment (now deleted) was not for your Question here, my mistake.

Comment: @iliasreventon The `LocalDateTime` class is exactly the *wrong* class to use with `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. That class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset.

Comment: @iliasreventon Regarding Android, reread my Answer more carefully.

Comment: @iliasreventon All of this has been covered many many times already as Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.